# Show that a metric space is complete and bounded but not compact

Tags: real-analysis

> Let X be a metric space
>   $$X = \{a=(a_0,a_1,...)\in \mathbf{R}^\mathbf{N}:\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_k|^2\leq 1\}$$
>   with the metric $d(a,b)=[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_k-b_k|^2]^{1/2}$.
>   show that $X$ is complete and bounded but not compact.

I first showed that X is a metric space and $X$ is bounded, I can also use the fact that $\mathbf{R}^k$ is complete for each $k\in \mathbf{N}$. But I have a difficult time showing that it is complete but not compact. Can anyone give me some hint or help? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Show $X$ contains a sequence with no converging subsequence.

Comment: @JackyChong Thanks, I use the sequence $(1,0,0,...), (0,1,0,...), (0,0,1,...)$ to show that $X$ is not compact. But how should I approach the completeness part?